# Calendar App Help - Adding Reminders To Date Buttons

Tags: android

I'm stuck on an application and was curious if anybody had a suggestion on how to accomplish what I'm looking to do. I made a custom calendar:

[image]

Each date was set up by a separate Adapter class and has an onClick method associated with it. I would like the user to be able to click on a date and be able to add different reminders for themselves that would appear in the TextView object where it says "Appointment 1."

The way I was thinking about solving this was creating an AlertDialog that would ask the user if they would like to add a reminder. If they click yes, a separate Activity would come up with just one field for now that would allow them to type something.

My main problem with that is that I don't know how to pass the data back, set it to my TextView ("Appointment 1") and have it be associated with the particular button that was clicked. The onClick method in my Adapter class does not allow me to implement StartActivityForResult nor will it allow me to create an onActivityResult() method.

This was the route that I was going down but clearly it won't work. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to accomplish this in a general sense? Maybe there's something I'm not thinking of. Thanks so much.